# Submit several forms from a single file and show updated information without refreshing

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a table showing information from a mysql table. I have three forms in it that add, delete or update the database like this :

```
<table>
  <form method="POST" action="php/delete.php">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nom</th>
        <th>Espéce</th>
        <th>Cri</th>
        <th>Propiétaire</th>
        <th>Age (années)</th>
        <th><input type="submit" name="supprimer" value="Supprimer" /></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <?php
        $connexion = mysql_connect($hote, $login, $mdp);
        mysql_select_db($bd, $connexion);

        $req = "Select * from animaux;";
        $resultat = mysql_query($req, $connexion);

        while (list($id, $nom, $esp, $cri, $prop, $age) = mysql_fetch_row($resultat)) {
      ?>

      <tr>
        <td><?= $nom ?> </td>
        <td><?= $esp ?></td>
        <td><?= $cri ?></td>
        <td><?= $prop ?></td>
        <td><?= $age ?></td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="choix[]" value=<?= $id ?>></td>
      </tr>
  </form>
  <form method="POST" action="php/maj.php">
      <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="num" value=<?= $id ?>/>
        <td><input id="nom-maj" type="text" name="nom" value=<?= $nom ?> /></td>
        <td><input id="esp-maj" type="text" name="esp" value=<?= $esp ?> /></td>
        <td><input id="cri-maj" type="text" name="cri" value=<?= $cri ?> /></td>
        <td><input id="prop-maj" type="text" name="prop" value=<?= $prop ?> /></td>
        <td><input id="age-maj" type="text" name="age" value=<?= $age ?>
                   onKeyPress='validationNombres(event)' maxlength="3" /></td>
        <td><input id="btn_maj" type="submit" name="maj" value="Mettre à jour"
        onclick=verif("maj") /></td>
      </tr>
  </form>

    <?php } ?>

  <form method="POST" action="php/add.php">  
      <tr>
        <td><input id="nom-add" type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nom" /></td>
        <td><input id="esp-add" type="text" name="esp" placeholder="Espéce" /></td>
        <td><input id="cri-add" type="text" name="cri" placeholder="Cri" /></td>
        <td><input id="prop-add" type="text" name="prop" placeholder="Propiétaire" /></td>
        <td><input id="age-add" type="text" name="age" placeholder="Âge"
                   onKeyPress='validationNombres(event)' maxlength="3"  /></td>
        <td><input id="btn-add" type="submit" name="ajouter" value="Ajouter"
        onclick=verif("add") /></td>
     </tr>

 </form> 

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Is there anyway to use this forms without having to leave the page, and also update the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try jquery post method..

```
$("input[name=supprimer]").click(function (e){

    e.preventDefaults(); 
    val = $("input[name=supprimer]").val();

    $.post(
            "php/delete.php", //Ajax file
            "supprimer":val,  // create an object will all values
            function (data) {

                   //Handle Response
                   alert(data.result);
            },
            "json"
        );



});
```

In your delete.php ;

```
if(isset($_POST["supprimer"]))
{
    $supprimer = $_POST["supprimer"];
    //Delete it, Let say result is true
    $result = true;
    echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));
}
```

You can try similar logic for others..

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). It's a feature of JavaScript that allows you to perform HTTP requests without refreshing the page. You can use JavaScript to fetch the values from your form and send them off to the target URL.

There's a nice tutorial on Ajax over at w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp